# VBA to insert rows where I have multiple tables aligned on one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Macro summary -
VBA (insert rows macro) : The code delivers a popup to ask for the number of rows to insert.
Then loops through and inserts rows across various worksheets in the workbook. Some worksheets have multiple locations that rows are inserted. The VBA then loops back through the same locations to copy down the formulas present in the last row of calculations prior to the insert rows.

Within the workbook there is a VBA sheet that, using calculations and inputs stores the last row numbers

[image: 1]

Workbook context -
On my tenancy worksheet I have several excel tables aligned across columns. They occupy rows 4-24 (inc total row). The tables contain data on current tenants, assumed future leases, lease review calculations etc. The data from these tables are then used throughout calculations in the rest of the workbook.
I used individual tables (rather than one huge table) to make referencing in formulas more intuitive throughout the workbook. It also helps the user to not get so overwhelmed when completing data entry initially.

Problem -
The macro runs into error 1004, insert method of Range class failed.

In stepping through it seems that in the first loop, when the macro picks up row 24 in the tenancy worksheet, it finds the correct row (24) to insert above but cant complete the task. I think its because I have multiple data tables across the page and even though they are all aligned excel wont let me insert rows.

I have confirmed in testing that Excel wont allow me to insert rows on this tenancy worksheet unless they are outside of the table structure (rows 4 - 24).

Code below

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub InsertRow()

'Sub to insert x rows throughout the work book

     
    Dim RowNum As Long
    Dim myLoop As Long
    Dim numberOfCells As Long
    Dim rowToInsert As Integer
    Dim SheetMyVar As String
    
    Dim mySheet As String
        
       
         
       'user input for rows
       
     RowNum = InputBox("Enter number of rows required.")
        If RowNum = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
     
       'turn off screen updates
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
        'go to AuditVB page
    Sheet26.Activate
        
        'get total number of times to run through loop by counting cells in the list of additional row locations
        numberOfCells = Range("D5", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Count
                
For myLoop = 1 To numberOfCells 'data on AuditVB sheet

            mySheet = Range("D4").Offset(myLoop, 6).Value  'this is sheet name
            
            rowToInsert = Range("D4").Offset(myLoop, 5).Value ' this is the row column
        
        'check if the 'sheet name' column has any data, if it does then check if the 'row number' reference is not equal to 0. If both conditions are met run through the loop
    If mySheet <> "" Then
    If rowToInsert <> 0 Then
                    
        With Sheets(mySheet).Activate 'activate the sheet name as per VBAudit page
            Rows(rowToInsert).Resize(RowNum).Insert 'Goto the row as stated on the VBAudit page
               
        End With
          
            
    Sheet26.Activate 'takes me back to the AuditVB worksheet

            
       End If
        End If
    
    Application.Calculate 'calculate the workbook so that the VBAudit references update and the rows are added in the correct spots.

    
Next myLoop

 
For myLoop = 1 To numberOfCells 'data on AuditVB sheet

            mySheet = Range("D4").Offset(myLoop, 6).Value  'this is sheet name
            
            rowToInsert = Range("D4").Offset(myLoop, 5).Value - RowNum ' this is the row column
        
        'check if the 'sheet name' column has any data, if it does then check if the 'row number' reference is not equal to 0. If both conditions are met run through the loop
    If mySheet <> "" Then
    If rowToInsert <> 0 Then
                    
        With Sheets(mySheet).Activate 'activate the sheet name as per VBAudit page
            Rows(rowToInsert).Offset(-1, 0).Copy _
            Rows(rowToInsert).Resize(RowNum, 1) 'Insert the number of rows stipluated in the original input box and copy down format and formula from the row previous

               
        End With
          
            
    Sheet26.Activate 'takes me back to the AuditVB worksheet

            
       End If
        End If
    
   
    
Next myLoop

  Application.Calculate 'calculate the workbook so that the VBAudit references update and the rows are added in the correct spots.

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Solution -
Without being an experienced VBA user I am not sure how to solve this other than just combining all of the tables on this page into a mega table. Is there an easier solution in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

- Row insertion raise runtime error 1004 if the row crosses over multiple tables (ListObject).
- The walkaround solution is using `Range(..).Insert`.

```
Sub demo()
    Rows(10).Insert ' no error
    ' Rows("3:4").Insert ' raise error 1004
    Range("A3:B4").Insert
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

> Question: The tables are all the same length in rows so adding rows to the bottom across all tables keeps them all aligned.

```vb
Sub demo2()
    Dim oTab As ListObject, i As Long
    Const ROW_CNT = 3
    For Each oTab In Sheet1.ListObjects
        For i = 1 To ROW_CNT
            oTab.ListRows.Add
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub demo2()
    Dim oTab As ListObject, i As Long
    Const ROW_CNT = 3
    For Each oTab In Sheet1.ListObjects
        With oTab
            .Resize .Range.Resize(.ListRows.Count + ROW_CNT + 1)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Taller. What I actually need to happen is to insert rows across all of the tables running across the page at the same time. The tables are all the same length in rows so adding rows to the bottom across all tables keeps them all aligned.

Comment: I've uploaded a code snippet. Please try it.